# Imagefield Crop - Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

Tags: media

I'm using [Imagefield Crop](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_crop) to resize images in my site after upload.

I have this JS error in the console after uploading my image :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

This line causes the error code in imagefield_crop.js :

```
var id = self_id.substring(0, self_id.indexOf('-cropbox'));
```

Can anyone confirm that this is a bug in the module ?

Thanks.